# at best vs. at most

Tags: word-choice

> Some may call such a view utopian - I see it as ambitious **at best/at most**.

Which of the two is more correct, if any?

Comment: I would argue **at best** is more appropriate here.

Comment: 'At best' is inappropriate here. The utopian view is being mildly criticised, and 'at best' doesn't work: 'at worst' would be nearer the sense. I'd rephrase to 'I see it as quite possibly ambitious, but not totally unrealistic.'

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary Wouldn't **at worst** imply that I perceive "ambitious" as something bad? I would like to make a contrast between "utopian" as something rather negative, and "ambitious" as something distinctly positive. And I would really like to keep the sentence structure.

Answer (score 2):

At best denotes quality; at most, quantity.

"I see it as ambitious at best" means "I hope it's mere ambition. It might be something a lot worse, like stupidity."

To use "at most," you need something measurable or countable. Try replacing it with "tops," see if it fits. "Fifty bucks is what you can get for it, tops." If it fits, use it.

Comment: So, based on your answer, would you also agree that **"at worst"** may actually be an appropriate solution? Saying I agree that both might be perceived negatively, however, if anything, the view is ambitious (as perhaps slightly negative), but surely not utopian (as clearly negative).

Comment: "At worst" would be the worst-case scenario. Logically you're correct. But it just doesn't sound right in this case.

Comment: Could you please take a look at Darshan Chaundary's answer below, wouldn't you agree with that?

Comment: @ziu: It's just one interpretation of your use of the word "utopian." Other interpretations are possible. Ask a question about that, and I'll give you an answer. Your question was about the difference between "at best" and "at most." I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence, you are criticizing the "utopian" view and wish to say "ambition" is better than that. I believe **at best** does exactly that:

> Some may call such a view utopian - I see it as ambitious **at best**

When you use **at best**, you show "utopian" in a bad light and assert that your view isn't "utopian", it is better - better by being not as bad as "utopian".

An alternative could be "**only**".

> Some may call such a view utopian - I see it as ambitious **only**.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like to say. I do not like the version with 'only', so I guess I'll go with 'at best'. In light of the comments above, I am a bit concerned though...

Comment: How about `Some may call such a view utopian - I see it as only ambitious.`

Comment: I just checked the thread to ask that same question - and there was the reply. :) This surely solves the problem, I just need to decide between these: **"I see it as only/merely patriotic"**, **I see it only/merely as patriotic" or **"I only/merely see it as patriotic"**. I actually think that the latter is more appropriate, an I prefer merely. Would you agree?